# Laravel 5.4 Image Intervention uploads images on S3 with 0 Bytes

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, bucket

I have successfully created a **Laravel 5.4** web application which is hosted on **Heroku**. I have also have managed that images gets uploaded on **AWS S3**. However the images gets uploaded as blank or empty. I have tried various online sources and have not been able to find a solution to my problem. Below I have attached my **controller**, which I believe is causing the error.

```
    public function updateavatar(Request $request, User $user){

if($request->hasFile('avatar')){

    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/avatars/');

    $imageS3 = Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300);

    Storage::disk("s3")->put($filename, $imageS3->__toString());
    //$disk->put("img/album/$id/$filename", $image->__toString());

$motcall = $this->carCheck($user);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();

}
```

An example how the issue looks like in my **bucket**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue by changign the storage line to Storage::disk("s3")->put($filename, file_get_contents($avatar)); 
P.S it ignores the image crop

Answer (score 0):

encode worked for me:

> for "s3"

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('/downloads/' . $fileName, $interventionImage->encode(), 'public');
```

> for local storage

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('/downloads/' . $fileName, $interventionImage->encode(), 'public');
```